# C++ STL Allocator on Shared Memory - Windows

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, shared-memory, allocator

Before I start, I would like to clarify two things:

1. I cannot use Boost IPC for this project, and I cannot use anything but original C/C++ libraries.
2. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613055/non-boost-stl-allocator-for-shared-memory) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222065/c-stl-map-in-shared-memory) for answers and still couldn't get the answer I wanted.

I am trying to store a `vector` in shared memory location. I have mapped a shared memory page and got its pointer. I also have created the `vector` itself on the shared memory using `placement new` and giving it the `LPVOID` of the map view:

```
hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
    NULL,                    // default security
    PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
    0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
    BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
    szName);                 // name of mapping object


if (hMapFile == NULL)
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),
        GetLastError());
    return 1;
}

pBuf = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,   // handle to map object
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
    0,
    0,
    BUF_SIZE);

if (pBuf == NULL)
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
        GetLastError());

    CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    return 1;
}

std::vector<int, shared_allocator<int>>* vec = new(pBuf) std::vector<int, shared_allocator<int>>;
```

Now, when I try accessing the memory from the second process, I am able to get hold of the `vector` itself and even print its `size()`. Obviously, I cannot access any of its data since it is all stored in the first process's heap.

From the code, it is clear I am using my custom allocator, which looks like this:

```
template <class T>
struct shared_allocator
{
    typedef T value_type;
    shared_allocator() noexcept {} //default ctor not required by C++ Standard Library    

                                                                 // A converting copy constructor:    
    template<class U> shared_allocator(const shared_allocator<U>&) noexcept {}
    template<class U> bool operator==(const shared_allocator<U>&) const noexcept
    {
        return true;
    }
    template<class U> bool operator!=(const shared_allocator<U>&) const noexcept
    {
        return false;
    }
    T* allocate(const size_t n) const;
    void deallocate(T* const p, size_t) const noexcept;
};

template <class T>
T* shared_allocator<T>::allocate(const size_t n) const
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (n > static_cast<size_t>(-1) / sizeof(T))
    {
        throw std::bad_array_new_length();
    }
    //void* const pv = malloc(n * sizeof(T));
    //if (!pv) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }
    //return static_cast<T*>(pv);

    return (T*) ::operator new(n*sizeof(T));
}

template<class T>
void shared_allocator<T>::deallocate(T * const p, size_t) const noexcept
{
    // free(p);
    delete(p);
}
```

This code was done following [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/allocators#writing-your-own-allocator-c11).

I replaced `malloc` and `free` with C++ `new` and `delete`. The code above works well and the first process can access everything.

Now I was trying to modify the allocator so it would allocate the newly created objects on the shared memory. So I changed the `allocate` function to:

```
template <class T>
T* shared_allocator<T>::allocate(const size_t n) const
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (n > static_cast<size_t>(-1) / sizeof(T))
    {
        throw std::bad_array_new_length();
    }
    //void* const pv = malloc(n * sizeof(T));
    //if (!pv) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }
    //return static_cast<T*>(pv);

    cnt += n*sizeof(T);
    void* p = (void*) (static_cast<char*>(pBuf) + cnt);

    return (T*) ::operator new(n*sizeof(T), p);
}
```

`cnt` is a global variable that starts as 0.

This is (obviously) not working. It crashes with some memory violation exceptions and all. I tried tracking the change of `cnt` and the first time it is incremented by 16, then by 4s.

The `vector` is not being filled with correct data since each time the `_MyFirst()` inside `vector` is being replaced with an address on the shared-memory.

I know I'm doing it wrong, but I have looked in many places and cannot seem to figure out how to get it right. How do I modify my `allocator` to correctly allocate on the shared-memory? If it alone can't, then would I need to re-create my own `vector`?

I have been following this [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/creating-stl-containers-in-shared-memory/184401639) and it shows that I only need to write an `allocator` to make this work.

Comment: shouldn't that be `(char*)pBuf  + sizeof(vector<int, shared_allocator<int> >) + cnt`? Since you constructed the vector in-place at the beginning of pBuf?

Comment: @PeterT Very true. I have changed it, at least now, my first pushed value is correct (I used to `push_back(0)` and get a random value as `vec[0]`). . Anyway, `vec[0]` is still stored in the process's heap, not in the shared memory. My second process is still unable to see `vec[0]`.

Comment: unless you want to rewrite pointers or use some relative-pointer wrapper type you're going to have to use `MapViewOfFileEx` with the same base-address in both processes. Not sure whether this is possible in windows, never tried it. But theretically using the same virtual address in two different processes should be fine

Comment: @PeterT Specifying base-address is not really practical and can break at any given moment. I would like a robust solution. As you mentioned, I need to work with pointers. My question is, where do I start and how should I modify them?

Comment: Does your shared memory occupy the same virtual address in both processes?

Comment: @RichardCritten Not necessarily.

Comment: Then the pointer (for the allocated memory) stored in the vector is going to point to the wrong virtual address in one of the processes.

Comment: I understand that, how can I make it point relatively?

Comment: @Everyone I don't think that's really feasible with std::vector

Comment: That is part of my question when I asked whether or not I need to re-create my own vector.

Comment: Try using `MapViewOfFile2` it lets you pick the base address (although how you choose a valid base address I have no idea).

Comment: @RichardCritten Most operating systems randomize the address space of the guest programs for security purposes. Even if I were able to pick one correctly and ran the programs well, I might run into trouble later in the future with this.

Comment: @Everyone have you managed to find a solution ?

Comment: @NorbertBoros i am afraid there is no easy way out. You need to re-implement the allocator in a custom way to make it allocate on shared memory. It's no easy task. Personally, I made a much simpler data structure and stored it instead.

Comment: @Everyone well.... :(. Can you share the structure design ?

Comment: @NorbertBoros it isn't very much related to the question. It's basically an array with fixed-size elements and fixed amount of entries.

Comment: @Everyone thanks, I did the same.